# Не запускается служба MySQL

Tags: mysql

Служба MySQL80 сама остановилась и отказывается запускаться. В файле `WIN-MUGGRCO16SH.err` такая картина:

> 2019-04-05T18:19:38.194213Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server]
>   'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql
>   modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict
>   mode in a future release.
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:38.196744Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.11) starting
>   as process 228
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:38.312441Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011971] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   Tablespace 'innodb_system' Page [page id: space=0, page number=5] log
>   sequence number 236694195998 is in the future! Current system log
>   sequence number 206772663820.
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:38.313517Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011972] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB
>   tablespace but not the InnoDB log files. Please refer to
>   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
>   for information about forcing recovery.
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:51.329476Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012611] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   Operating system error number 1117 in a file operation.
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:51.329864Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012646] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   File .\ibdata1: 'Windows aio' returned OS error 1217. Cannot continue
>   operation
>
> 2019-04-05T18:19:51.330236Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012981] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   Cannot continue operation.
>
> 2019-04-05T18:21:41.596335Z 1 [Warning] [MY-012928] [InnoDB] InnoDB:
>   10 threads created by InnoDB had not exited at shutdown!

Как это возможно - "*Your database may be corrupt or you may have copied the InnoDB tablespace but not the InnoDB log files*"? Работала база и вдруг "*corrupt*"...

Я с базой работаю как пользователь - запросы и не более. Но так сложилось, что администрировать её сейчас больше некому, поэтому прошу помощи. Как исправить эти ошибки и запустить службу (желательно с сохранением 50 ГБ данных)?

Comment: восстановить из бэкапа? Вообще, если бы был включен бинарный лог, то данные сами бы могли восстановиться. У меня такой случай был, не восстановилась только одна запись после сбоя

Comment: @ArchDemon, как это делается? Я даже не могу зайти под рутом, так как не стартует служба. Не могли бы вы описать порядок действий?

Comment: Есть каталог, где хранятся данные (файл ibdata1 ищите). Ваши базы данных оттуда нужно убрать и попробовать запустить сервер. Если будет успешно, залить данные из бэкапа.

Comment: @ArchDemon, вот судя по логам как раз с этим файлом и проблема. Как из него убрать базы, через notepad?

Comment: Нет. Ищите этот файл. Найдёте каталог с этим файлом, а дальше делаете резервную копию и удаляете по очереди файлы, которые не жалко. Попутно проверяя запуск службы.

Answer (score 1):

Запустил службу с флагом `[mysqld]` `innodb_force_recovery = 6`. С меньшими параметрами не запускалось. Проверка выявила много повреждённых таблиц, но это лучше чем бэкапы недельной давности.